# Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry

Tags: registry, rcp

I am trying to build an RCP Application as done [here](http://www.eclipse.org/articles/article.php?file=Article-Adapters/index.html).

Sadly i am gettin an error message that doesn't makes much sense to me. Maybe one of you has an idea.

```
 !SESSION 2013-07-12 14:31:25.331 -----------------------------------------------
eclipse.buildId=unknown
java.version=1.7.0_07
java.vendor=Oracle Corporation
BootLoader constants: OS=win32, ARCH=x86, WS=win32, NL=de_DE
Framework arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench
Command-line arguments:  -application org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench -data C:\Users\ccoen\Desktop\workspace/../runtime-de.vogella.rcp.editor.example.application -dev file:C:/Users/ccoen/Desktop/workspace/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.pde.core/de.vogella.rcp.editor.example.application/dev.properties -os win32 -ws win32 -arch x86 -consoleLog

!ENTRY org.eclipse.osgi 4 0 2013-07-12 14:31:25.721
!MESSAGE Application error
!STACK 1
java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry. The applications available are: org.eclipse.ant.core.antRunner, org.eclipse.equinox.app.error.
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.EclipseAppContainer.startDefaultApp(EclipseAppContainer.java:248)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.app.MainApplicationLauncher.run(MainApplicationLauncher.java:29)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.runApplication(EclipseAppLauncher.java:110)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.internal.adaptor.EclipseAppLauncher.start(EclipseAppLauncher.java:79)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:344)
    at org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter.run(EclipseStarter.java:179)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.invokeFramework(Main.java:622)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.basicRun(Main.java:577)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.run(Main.java:1410)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.launcher.Main.main(Main.java:1386)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, it's done.I had to add the 'org.eclipse.core.runtime.applications' to my Extensions.

Answer (score 2):

Another approach that worked for me when **developing an Eclipse plugin** (not a standalone RCP application) and getting the *"`java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench" could not be found in the registry.`"* exception (I found this SO thread when googling this error, and also found the following):
https://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php?t=msg&th=155457&goto=820447&#msg_820447

You have to go to "*Run Configurations...*", and on the "Plug-ins" tab, you also have to MANUALLY check **`org.eclipse.ui.ide.application`** plug-in. That's all (or maybe you'll also need `org.eclipse.core.net`, I didn't need it).

Previously I clicked "*Add Required Plug-ins*", "*Validate Plug-ins*", but none of them marked this plug-in as needed, so I got this exception all the time I wanted to start a new Eclipse instance. By adding it manually, the problem got away.

Answer (score 0):

For the error message

> java.lang.RuntimeException: Application "org.eclipse.ui.ide.workbench"
>   could not be found in the registry.

the easiest solution I found is to add the plugin called `'org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator'`. This works especially for the latest eclipse versions (in my case Neon.3 v4.*).

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to solve that problem in Eclipse is:

```
-> Go to "Run" and select "Run Configurations"
-> Go to "Plug-ins"-Tab and hit the "Add Required Plug-ins"-Button
-> Than Apply!
```

Eclipse will automatically select all the plugins needed.